# Why is std::pair from anonymous object copying that object instead of moving?

Tags: c++, stl, std-pair

I tried to make `std::pair` with this style:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() noexcept {
        std::cout << "Created\n";
    }
    A(const A&) noexcept {
        std::cout << "Copy\n";
    }
    A(A&&) noexcept {
        std::cout << "Move\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::pair<A, A> a{ {},{} };
    return 0;
}
```

and got such output:

```
Created
Created
Copy
Copy
```

instead of

```
Created 
Created
Move
Move
```

But if I define my anonymous object type (e.g. `std::pair<A, A> a{A{}, A{}}`)
or use `std::make_pair<A, A>({}, {})` I get right result.

`std::pair` constructor must use `std::forward<U1>` and `std::forward<U2>` to initialize objects, thus I think that my pair uses wrong constructor. Why?

Comment: even with C++20 it still calls the copy ctor

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Which version of the compiler? What flags and options do you pass to the compiler when you build?

Comment: I didn't use any optimization,  I compile it on clang and msvc (std::c++17 both)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There's a problem with how `std::pair` is defined. I'd even say it's a minor defect in the standard.

It has two constructors that could be used here:

1. `pair(const T1 &x, const T2 &y);`, where `T1`, `T2` are template parameters of the `pair`.
2. `template <class U1, class U2> pair(U1 &&x, U2 &&y);`

If you do `std::pair<A, A> a{A{}, A{}});`, then the second constructor is selected and all is well.

But if you do `std::pair<A, A> a{{}, {}};`, the compiler can't use the second constructor because it can't deduce `U1`, `U2`, because `{}` by itself has no type. So the first constructor is used and you get a copy.

For it to work properly, `std::pair` should have an extra non-template constructor `pair(T1 &&, T2 &&)`, and for a good measure two extra constructors: `pair(const T1 &, T2 &&)` and `pair(T1 &&, const T2 &)`.

Comment: Reminds me of Herb Sutter's Twitter question for the CppCon talk: https://twitter.com/herbsutter/status/1305292734966558721 ‍♂️

Comment: I would rather it have a different one instead of those two it has: `template <class U1 = T1, class U2 = T2> pair(U1&& x, U2&& y)`. That change might necessitate a new deduction guide though.